# Function Prototype Error, Expected '=' ... before 'int'

Tags: c, function-prototypes

I have ran into an unexpected error while running my C code. My code works perfectly fine when I put my main function last and declare no function prototypes, but it does not work fine when I put main first and declare my function prototypes.

These are the names of my functions in order:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// code here
}

int b_s(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
// code
}

void print(char *Table[], int n)
{
// code here
}
a
int ins(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
// code here
}

void empt(char *Table[], int n)
{
// code here
}
```

And this is how I declare my prototypes below the preprocessors:

```
int b_s(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
void print(char *Table[], int n)
int ins(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
void empt(char *Table[], int n)
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
In function 'b_s':|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
error: expected '{' at end of input|
```

I was wondering if I am just declaring my prototypes wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `;` after each function declaration.like 
`int b_s(char *word, char *Table[], int n);`

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I actually missed something so simple. Comes to show that you should not code for more than 8 hours. Thanks for the reply! I'll make sure to pick your answer.

Comment: In addition to @coderredoc, maybe you get it while you are writing this post, but between `print()` and `ins()` you have an 'a', which probably will restrict the compilation